# How to show user profile data in codeigniter with session?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in CI and I have make login system but I am trying to show user profile data in username and email are show on user profile view page. I am to much try but I cant solve this issue. Here is my code.
Can one tell me about how to show user profile data in profile view page? I have too much trying but no solution is available for showing a user profile data in codeigniter.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UserLogin extends CI_Controller
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->view('UserLoginPage');
    }

    public function userLoginProcess()
    {
      // $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
      // echo "login reached";
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|alpha|trim');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");
      $this->session->set_flashdata("<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");


        if ($this->form_validation->run() ){
            //username aur password araha hay
              $username = $this->input->post('username');
                    $password = $this->input->post('password');

              $this->load->model('login_model');

              //$loginObj session ko check variable haa..!
              $loginObj = $this->login_model->login_valid($username,$password);
              if($loginObj){
                   // print_r($loginObj->password);
                   $this->session->set_userdata('userSessionObj', $loginObj);
                   //print_r($loginObj);
                           $this->load->view('userDashboard');
                }
                else{
               // echo "<script>alert('UserName And Passowrd Are Wrong....!!!! ');</script>";
              // $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');
              $this->load->view('UserLoginPage');
              // echo "<script language=\"javascript\">alert('Username And Password Are Worng');</script>";
              $this->session->set_flashdata('error','<p class="text-danger"> you entered invalid username and password');
                }   // end of else

        }  // end of public function
        else
            {

                $this->load->view('userLoginPage');

            } // end of else

      }  //end of function
    //logout function Start
    public function logout()
    {
      $this->session->sess_destroy();
      $this->session->unset_userdata('username','password');
       return redirect("userLogin");
    }
        //logout function End
    public function register()
    {

       $this->load->view('registered');

    } //end of register function
    public function preRegister()
    {
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|alpha|trim|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[user.username]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email','required|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword', 'ConfirmPassword','required|matches[password]');


      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");

      if($this->form_validation->run())
      {
        $store = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'dateOfbirth' => $this->input->post('dateOfbirth'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        'confirmpassword'=> $this->input->post('confirmpassword'),
        'gender' => $this->input->post('gender')
        );

          $this->login_model->insert_mod($store);
          redirect('UserLogin/index');

      } // end of if form_validation
      else
      {
          $this->load->view('registered');

      } // end of else

  }  //end of preRegister function

  public function employess()   // employes of add ka page view kr rha haaaa
    {
            $this->load->view('userDashboard');
    }                          // employes of add ka page view kr rha haaaa

  public function proEmployess()
  {

    // $this->load->view('addEmployess');
    // $this->load->view('addEmployess');
    $employessData = array(
    // 'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
    'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
    'department' => $this->input->post('department')
    );

      $this->login_model->employess_add($employessData);
      redirect('UserLogin/employess');
  }

  public function myProfile(){

    // $myProfile = $this->session->userdata();
    $this->load->view('headerDashboard.php');
    $myProfiledata ['profiles'] = $this->login_model->profileVeiw();
    $this->load->view('myProfileView', $myProfiledata);
    $this->load->view('footerDashboard.php');
  }

  //  public function myProfile(){
  //
  //     $this->load->view('headerDashboard');
  //     //$myProfiledata ['datas'] = $this->login_model->veiw_Employess();
  //     //$employessRecord['datas'] = $this->login_model->veiw_Employess();
  //     $this->load->view('myProfileView');
  //     $this->load->view('footerDashboard');
  //
  // }
}
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_model extends CI_Model{

    public function login_valid($username ,$password)
    {
        $q = $this->db->where(['username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password])
                        ->get('user');


        if( $q->num_rows() )
        {
            //return pori row ho rhe ha jo database sa arhe haaa
             return $q->row();
            // return $q->row()->id;
            // return TRUE;
        }
else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

    }

    public function insert_mod($store)
    {
        $this->db->insert('user', $store);
    }
    public function employess_add($employessData)
    {
        $this->db->insert('employessRecord',$employessData);
    }
    public function view_employess(){

        $query = $this->db->get('employessrecord');
        return $query;
    }public function profileVeiw(){

              $queries = $this->db->get('user');
             //$queries = $this->session->userdata();
            // print_r($queries);
            return $queries;

        }
}
<div class="col-xl-6">
        <div class="card" >
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>Profile Details</h4>
            </div><br>
            <?php foreach($profiles->result() as $profile):?>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <label for="name">Username:</label>
              <?php echo $profile->username;?>
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <label for="address">Email:</label>
              <?php echo $profile->email;?>
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <label for="address">Passowrd:</label>
              <?php echo $profile->password;?>
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <label for="address">Gender:</label>
              <?php echo $profile->gender;?>
            </div><br><br>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Look what we've got [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/)... a codeigniter tutorial... If there is more on this topic read that too and report back here with an edit your own question if some error pops up. If not and solved post a self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is opening tag php tag

so you received the data from form and inserted it in database `$this->login_model->insert_mod($store)` .

when you call myProfile function you get data in `$myProfiledata ['profiles'] = $this->login_model->profileVeiw();` here and passed it to view. if this is correct then first try to print `$myProfiledata` before passing to the view if everything ok there then try to print  `$profiles` on the "myProfileView" view.

$this->session->userdata('userSessionObj');
 here you can check the session data